# The transfer attempted appeared to contain a data leak?

Tags: asp.net, proxy

Getting this error message in the browser:

> Attention!!!
>
> The transfer attempted appeared to contain a data leak!
>
> URL=http://test-login.becreview.com/domain/User_Edit.aspx?UserID=b5d77644-b10e-44e0-a007-3b9a5e0f4fff

I've seen this before but I'm not sure what causes it. It doesn't look like a browser error or an asp.net error. Could it be some sort of proxy error? What causes it?

That domain is internal so you won't be able to go to it. Also the page has almost no styling. An h1 for "Attention!!!" and the other two lines are wrapped in p tags if that helps any.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone else investigating this message, it appears to be a Fortinet firewall's default [network data-leak prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_loss_prevention_software#Network_DLP_.28aka_Data_in_Motion_.3CDiM.3E.29) message.

Comment: For those who don't know: Fortinet's firewall is implemented via a network hardware device (ex. Fortigate). In other words, you cannot override this policy from your workstation. You should contact your network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an ASP.NET error that I've ever seen.

If you think it might be a proxy message you should reconfigure your browser so it does not use a proxy server, or try to access the same URL from a machine that has direct access to the web server (and doesn't use the same proxy).

Answer (score 0):

This is generated from an inline IPS sensor (usually an appliance or a VM) that is also configured to scan traffic for sensitive data (CC info, SSNs etc). Generally speaking, the end user cannot detect or bypass this proxy as it is deployed to be transparent. It is likely also inspecting all SSL traffic. In simple terms, it is performing a MITM attack because your organizational policy has specified that all traffic to and from your network be inspected.